# remove zeroes in 1 column vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Let me replace my question,

```
=INDEX('" & Filename & folder1 & "[" & ffname1 & "]Customers'!C21,MATCH(C6,'" & Filename & folder1 & "[" & ffname1 & "]Customers'!C2,0))
```

This is my code for matching some data to my master file.
My problem is, if the column for matching is blank or have an empty value the output of the matching is equal to **0**
I want the output to be exact as what is in the master file.

for example, if some of the cells are blanks, it should be blank. But I don't know how.

I don't know how to explain it but I guess you guys know what I'm saying I hope??. Is just like returning 0 in vlookup?

Answer (score -2):

no need to answer this question guys!! I already solved my problem :D I used IFERROR(IF(...)) formular for this

Comment: Rather than post this as an answer better add comment to loud your voice to address the audience , or post the complete Formula which has rectified the issue as an answer!!